# Real time one-to-one messages in Rachet

Tags: php, ratchet

I am just learning Ratchet (library used for real time chat applications in PHP). As per the documentation, the following function will receive two things:

1. from whom the message came and
2. message.

However, it misses whom to send. This function sends the message to all people who are connected. But I want implement one to one chat as well. Is there a way to do it?

Here is the link for that library: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    //send the message to all the other clients except the one who sent.
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from !== $client) {
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't it already has room to limit one to one message? dunno never used it before.

Comment: you can try https://github.com/php-pure/sacky-server

Comment: @sugumar it would be great if you can post how you finally did it, as people like me came looking for answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make different subscriptions per chat the user wants.

One channel for the chat messages between everyone: subscriptionname = room123

And for each personal chat you could use a different signature: subscriptionname = personal456.

Then let your clientside application listen to 2 diffent subscriptions and try to route it depending on what the name of the subscription that received the message is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do one-to-one messages. However, these still have to go via the socket server - you cannot do direct peer-to-peer messaging between browsers. Each user has a permanently open connection, but only with the server.

What you will need to do is to store usernames against each client connection, so that when you traverse `$this->clients`, you can retrieve either the connection or the username. Then, you can broadcast this list to all subscribers, subject to whatever privacy constraints are required by your design.

Finally, each user may then send a private message, by specifying:

- the message text
- the username to whom it is addressed

This will be received by Ratchet, and from there you can do a connection lookup in `$this->clients` using the username. The connection you end up with, if it is still open, is the connection to use to forward the message.

You can optionally send an "ack" (acknowledgement) to the originator to say that their message was (or was not) delivered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with filtering out the clients is, according to the documentation, connection objects are reused, meaning you can actually have more than one client sharing the same connection object.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Comment: OK, I'm trying to implement a one to one chat using Ratchet, but Ratchet documentation reads, connection objects are shared, and to the best of my knowledge, I think what that implies is, there may be scenarios where two or more clients share a single connection object. And considering the fact that the API works with sending messages to Connection objects, we might run into a situation where two or more clients get receive the same message from the server even if they are different clients entirely